# OpenCV preprocess image for better thresholding results

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, threshold

In OpenCV, how can I preprocess images for better thresholding results? My input image is

[base image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qJnB.png)

I am using a variety of thresholding methods like:

**EDIT**

Applying `CLAHE (Contrast Limited Adaptive Histogram Equalization)` significantly decreases the amount of noise but the text extracted is still kind of blurry. Is there a way I can make the text more "crisp"?

```
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=1.0, tileGridSize=(3,3))
inputImage = clahe.apply(inputImage)
```

**END OF EDIT**

```
invertRet, invertColors = cv2.threshold(inputImage,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

gaussianThreshold = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(inputImage, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2)

adaptiveMean = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(inputImage, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2)

otsuRet, otsu = cv2.threshold(inputImage,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

but they all display lots of noise like:

[gaussian thresholding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIDQW.png)

Comment: use clahe or histogram equalize

Comment: Have you tried filtering the noise out using cv2.gaussianBlur or a bilateral or median filter?

Comment: My goal is to extract characters from the threshold image. Will blurring it affect the results later on?